# Apply Custom decorator to dispatch in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have written decorator here is the code.

```
def is_envlocked(func):
    def is_lockedwrapper(self):
        username = "tejesh.s"
        env_id = self.object.env_id
        env = Capacity.models.Env.objects.get(id=env_id)
        if env.user == username:
            return True
        else:
           return reverse('envapps', kwargs={'envid':self.object.env.id})
   return is_lockedwrapper

class EnvappsCreate(CreateView):
    model = Capacity.models.Envapps
    fields=['appname','VM_Image','functional_count','flavor']
    template_name = 'envapps_create_form.html'
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request,envid):
     return super(EnvappsCreate, self).dispatch(request)
```

But want to add this decorator to dispatch method how can i do that?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use multiple decorators on dispatch method?

Comment: yes, i tried but i'm not able access the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). You can do one of the following:

```
decorators = [login_required, is_envlocked]
@method_decorator(decorators)
def dispatch(self, request, envid):
```

Or use `method_decorator()` multiple times:

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
@method_decorator(is_envlocked)
def dispatch(self, request, envid):
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i access self object inside my decorator , it's showing  object has no attribute 'object'.

Comment: There is no object (this is a view decorator). You should probably be replacing instances of `self.object` with `request`.